# Error : Method missing for Active record query : find_by_attribute_name('test_data') not working

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I Transferred data from oracle db to mysql db and trying to access data through query `Model_Name.find_by_attribute_name('test_data')`

My tables having attribute name in capital letters. when trying to fetch data with attribute name in lower case, generating error "method missing"

EG:

table_name(Product)(ID(1),CODE("Test))

working :   Product.find_by_CODE("Test")

Not Working: Product.find_by_code("Test")

error : `gems/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in`method_missing': undefined method `find_by_code' for #<Class:0x00000005fee8b8> (NoMethodError)`

I was not having case sensitive issue in oracle db.

Please help me out with this .
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have clear first what is your column name `CODE` or `code`

Comment: Column name in mysql is in uppercase (CODE). When I am accessing 'find_by_code' it fails. It works when I use 'find_by_CODE'

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `CODE` is a reserved word in MySQL, so you can't use it as a column name: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

You'll have to rename your column to something that isn't on that list and everything should be fine.